# merge lines startimg from pattern to next pattern excluding second patten

Tags: bash, awk, sed

Input:

```
@@string1
string2,
word
@@string3
string4,
word
@@string5, word
```

Desired output:

```
@@string1string2,word
@@string3,string4,word
@@string5, word
```

Tried

```
sed -n '/^@@/{:a;N;/^@@/!ba};/^@@/s/\n//g;p'
```

Not working

Comment: Why is there a comman between string3 and string4, but not between string1 and string2 in your output?

Comment: its a csv but some command gone wrong and it splitted inplace

Comment: How is a program supposed to be able to tell the difference (the currently accepted answer doesn't attempt to tell the difference and so doesn't produce the expected output)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `sed (GNU sed) 4.7`, try

```
sed -z 's/\n//g; s/@@\|$/\n&/2g' file
@@string1string2,word
@@string3string4,word
@@string5, word
```